# Nested views with dot notation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

can someone help me with this nested views in angular js. 
I use this dot notation

```
  $stateProvider
  .state('contacts/:id', {
  templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
  controller: function($scope){
  $scope.contacts = [{ name: 'Alice' },       { name: 'Bob' }];
   }
   })
  .state('contacts/:id.list/:id', {
   templateUrl: 'contacts.list.html'
   });

  function MainCtrl($state){
     $state.transitionTo('contacts/:id.list/:id'       );
  }
```

In html I call state change also like this

```
<a ui-sref="contacts/{{value.id}}.list/{{value.id}}">get<\a>
```

But always I get

> angular.js:12477 Error: Could not resolve 'contact/2.list/2' from state 'contact/:id'

Thnx

EDIT:

---

I make a change like @Maxim Shoustin answered. Now state changed, but in child navigation when I click on item, parent ui-view is full refreshed (child navigation and ui-view) not only child  
now my state looks like this

```
.state('client', {
                url: '/client/info/:itemID',
                templateUrl: 'clientInfo.html',
                controller: 'detailControllerClient as vm',
            })
            .state('client.detail', {
                url: '/detail/:itemID',
                templateUrl: 'itemInfoById.html',
                controller: 'detailControllerClient as vm',
            })
```

And html is here. (infoDisplay.html is parent view inside index.html. This ui-view in code bellow is child view (client.detail))
infoDisplay.html

```
<div class="new_nav col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <table class="table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>item ID</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>   
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in clientDetail">
                        <td><a ui-sref=".detail({'itemID': value.id})">{{value.id}}</a></td>     
                    </tr>   
                </tbody> 
            </table>
        </div>
        <div ui-view></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<a ui-sref="contacts/{{value.id}}.list/{{value.id}}">get<\a>`

You cannot use `id.list` with `id` because Angular determines like duplicated name `id` in pattern. But `id_list` is ok. For example

See [ui-sref](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/quick-reference#ui-sref) Docs

Where state is:

```
.state('contacts', {
    url: '/contacts/:id_list/:id',  
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html'
  })
```

and HTML:

```
<a ui-sref="contacts({'id_list': value.id, 'id': value.id})" >contacts</a>
```

[Demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FCir5BByPRCX0GShFU6g?p=preview)

Comment: Im sorry... it's mistake... it's ui-sref not ui-state... here is example with dot in url https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views vut for me this doesn't working...

Comment: @Arter well, its not what you wrote.  :)  `id.list` in your case is parameter but not state

Comment: It has sense :) ... Your answer before is solution or I need change something else? In monday I will try this when I come back to work... and i will response to you with result. Thnx man for this